# Magento - set currency when creating order programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, currency

I have a dev magento with multi-currency enabled (GBP, EUR , USD). I am trying to create a sales order against my dev magento in **Euro** - however the order keeps creating in GBP (my base currency).

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Here's my code so far:

```
<?php

// Init Magento In Admin Store Context
require_once '/home/www-data/public_html/app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// Function To Generate Magento Sales Order
function CreateOrder($orderData = array())
{
    // Validate Order Data
    if (!sizeof($orderData)) {
        exit('Invalid Order Data');
    }
    $orderData = (object)$orderData;
    if (!sizeof($orderData->BasketData)) {
        exit('Sales Order Basket Cannot Be Empty');
    }

    // Anticipate Error
    try
    {
        // Start New Sales Order Quote
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
                 ->setStoreId($orderData->StoreId);

        // Set Sales Order Quote Currency
        $quote->setCurrency($orderData->Currency);

        // Load Sales Order Customer
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setWebsiteId($orderData->CustomerWebsiteId)
                    ->load($orderData->CustomerId);

        // Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

        // Configure Notification
        $quote->setSendCconfirmation($orderData->SendConfirmation ? '1' : '0');

        // Add Products To Sales Order Quote
        foreach ($orderData->BasketData as $orderLine)
        {
            // Add Product To Sales Order Quote
            $quote->addProduct(
                Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderLine['ProductId']),
                new Varien_Object(array(
                    'price' => floatval($orderLine['Price']),
                    'qty'   => intval($orderLine['Qty'])
                ))
            );
        }

        // Set Sales Order Billing Address
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
            'firstname'  => $orderData->BillingAddress['Firstname'],
            'lastname'   => $orderData->BillingAddress['Lastname'],
            'company'    => $orderData->BillingAddress['Company'],
            'street'     => array($orderData->BillingAddress['AddressLine1'], $orderData->BillingAddress['AddressLine2']),
            'region_id'  => 0,
            'region'     => $orderData->BillingAddress['Region'],
            'city'       => $orderData->BillingAddress['City'],
            'postcode'   => $orderData->BillingAddress['Postcode'],
            'country_id' => getCountryId($orderData->BillingAddress['Country']),
            'telephone'  => $orderData->BillingAddress['Telephone']
        ));

        // Set Sales Order Shipping Address
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
            'firstname'  => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Firstname'],
            'lastname'   => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Lastname'],
            'company'    => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Company'],
            'street'     => array($orderData->ShippingAddress['AddressLine1'], $orderData->ShippingAddress['AddressLine2']),
            'region_id'  => 0,
            'region'     => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Region'],
            'city'       => $orderData->ShippingAddress['City'],
            'postcode'   => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Postcode'],
            'country_id' => getCountryId($orderData->ShippingAddress['Country']),
            'telephone'  => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Telephone']
        ));

        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod($orderData->ShippingMethod)
                        ->setPaymentMethod($orderData->PaymentMethod);

        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => $orderData->PaymentMethod));

        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();

        // Create Order From Quote
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
        $service->submitAll();
        $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getIncrementId();

        // Resource Clean-Up
        $quote = $customer = $service = null;

        // Finished
        return $increment_id;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // Error
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}

// HELPER FUNCTION
function getCountryId($countryName) {
    $countryId = '';
    $countryCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getCollection();
    foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
        if ($countryName == $country->getName()) {
            $countryId = $country->getCountryId();
            break;
        }
    }
    $countryCollection = null;
    return $countryId;
}

// TEST Order Create Function
echo CreateOrder(array(
    'Currency'          => 'EUR', // Euro
    'StoreId'           => 3,     // Trade Store View
    'CustomerWebsiteId' => 2,     // Trade Website
    'CustomerId'        => 5,     // Latheesan K.
    'SendConfirmation'  => false,
    'BasketData'        => array
    (
        array('ProductId' => 3, 'Price' => 13.00, 'Qty' => 1), // VCF001
        array('ProductId' => 6, 'Price' =>  1.00, 'Qty' => 1), // VCF002
        array('ProductId' => 8, 'Price' => 14.99, 'Qty' => 1), // VCF003
    ),
    'BillingAddress'    => array
    (
        'Firstname'     => 'Latheesan',
        'Lastname'      => 'Kanes',
        'Company'       => 'Intelli B.I. Ltd',
        'AddressLine1'  => 'Unit 1, Eastman Road',
        'AddressLine2'  => 'Acton',
        'Region'        => '',
        'City'          => 'London',
        'Postcode'      => 'W3 7QS',
        'Country'       => 'United Kingdom',
        'Telephone'     => '0208 428 2832',
    ),
    'ShippingAddress'   => array
    (
        'Firstname'     => 'Latheesan',
        'Lastname'      => 'Kanes',
        'Company'       => 'Intelli B.I. Ltd',
        'AddressLine1'  => 'Unit 1, Eastman Road',
        'AddressLine2'  => 'Acton',
        'Region'        => '',
        'City'          => 'London',
        'Postcode'      => 'W3 7QS',
        'Country'       => 'United Kingdom',
        'Telephone'     => '0208 428 2832',
    ),
    'ShippingMethod'    => 'flatrate_flatrate',
    'PaymentMethod'     => 'checkmo'
));

?>
```

Also, this line isn't turning on email notification on order create:

```
// Configure Notification
$quote->setSendCconfirmation($orderData->SendConfirmation ? '1' : '0');
```

How do you enable email notification?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to make your switch happen way sooner then you are, right after `$app` is checked for.  Also, try converting the prices, and also testing that you have what you expect.  Here are some things to get you rolling.

## Convert Price from Current Currency to Base Currency and vice-versa

```
<?php
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$price = 100;

// convert price from current currency to base currency
$priceOne = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $currentCurrencyCode, $baseCurrencyCode); 

// convert price from base currency to current currency
$priceTwo = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode);
?>
```

## Changing price from any one currency to another

```
<?php
$from = 'USD';
$to = 'NPR';
$price = 10;

$newPrice = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $from, $to);
?>
```

## Get Currency Rates

```
<?php
/**
 * Get the base currency
 */
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();

/**
 * Get all allowed currencies
 * returns array of allowed currency codes
 */
$allowedCurrencies = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies();

/**
 * Get the currency rates
 * returns array with key as currency code and value as currency rate
 */
$currencyRates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates($baseCurrencyCode, array_values($allowedCurrencies));

$allowedCurrencies = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies();

/**
 * Get currency rates for Nepalese Currency
 */
$currencyRates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates('NPR', array_values($allowedCurrencies));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to do both

```
$quote->setBaseCurrencyCode($currencyCode);
$quote->setQuoteCurrencyCode($currencyCode);
```

You may want to checkout this magerun command that creates orders:
https://github.com/kalenjordan/magerun-addons/blob/master/src/KJ/Magento/Command/Order/Create/Dummy.php#L178

See if it sets the currency properly from within your dev environment, and if it does, you should be able to follow that same recipe.

Disclaimer: There are still some things hard-coded in that command that should be cleaned up, but should be enough there for the currency to get set right.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a certain store while processing the order. This will temporarely run Magento on a different store level using Euro.
[This Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/) article will help give you the code to do so.

About sending emails. 'Confirmation' should only have 1 C, you've spelled it with two.

Comment: My stores aren't linked to the currencies (like my production environment) - so I can't really do this. Is there no other way of setting the currency on the order?

Comment: I dumped the **$quote** object to see what was in there and saw this:

    [global_currency_code] => GBP
    [base_currency_code] => GBP
    [store_currency_code] => GBP
    [quote_currency_code] => GBP
    [store_to_base_rate] => 1
    [store_to_quote_rate] => 1
    [base_to_global_rate] => 1
    [base_to_quote_rate] => 1

So, I tried to set these value manually like so:

$quote->setQuoteCurrencyCode($orderData->CurrencyCode;
$quote->setStoreToQuoteRate($orderData->ExchangeRate);
$quote->setBaseToQuoteRate($orderData->ExchangeRate);

It doesn't work. It reverts back to GBP during quote save.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. The solution for me was to use the following code:

```
$currency = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load('USD');
$quote->setForcedCurrency($currency);
```

This code will be use in the function `\Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::_beforeSave` and you currency will be used as intended.

The above code will use the USD currency for your order when you base currency is not USD.