# magento 1.9 Create order programmatically in aed currency with aed rate

Tags: orders, currency, programmatically, multicurrency, currency-rates

I want to create order in aed currency. In store, there is only 2 currency 1 is pkr which is base currency and other is aed. When I switch PKR to AED order place in pkr.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//error_reporting(0);
$cur_id="";
require_once("app/Mage.php");
try{
function mres($value)
{
$search = array("\\",  "\x00", "\n",  "\r",  "'",  '"', "\x1a");
$replace = array("\\\\","\\0","\\n", "\\r", "\'", '\"', "\\Z");

return str_replace($search, $replace, $value);
}
$product_id = mres( $_POST['product_id'] );
$fname = mres( $_POST['fname'] );
$lname = "&nbsp;";
$email=uniqid().".customer@abc.pk";
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
if($_POST['email']!="")
{
    $email = mres($_POST['email']);
}
}
if($fname=="")
{
$fname="Guest";
$lname="Customer";
}
$sphone= str_replace(' ', '',mres( $_POST['phone']));
$dphone= str_replace('-', '', $sphone);
$dotphone= str_replace('.', '', $dphone);
$cphone= str_replace(',', '', $dotphone);
$pphone= str_replace('+', '', $cphone);
if (strpos($pphone, '0') === 0) {
    $pphone = ltrim($pphone, "0");
    if (strpos($pphone, '92') === false) {
        $pphone="92".$pphone;
    }
}
else if (strpos($pphone, '92') === false) {
    $pphone="92".$pphone;
}
//echo $pphone;
$phone = $pphone;
$mobile = mres( $_POST['mobile'] );
$city = mres( $_POST['city'] );
$country = mres( $_POST['country'] );
$address = mres( $_POST['address'] );
$quantity = mres( $_POST['quantity'] );
$comments = mres( $_POST['comments'] );
$currency=mres($_POST['currency']);
if(isset($_POST['optionsss']))
{
$optionsss = mres( $_POST['optionsss'] );
$color = mres( $_POST['color'] );
}
//$productids = array(1, 2, 4, 3);
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
// Start New Sales Order Quote
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getId());

// Set Sales Order Quote Currency
$quote->setCurrency($currency);
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
        ->loadByEmail($email);
if ($customer->getId() == "") {
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname($fname)
            ->setLastname($lname)
            ->setEmail($email)
            ->setPassword("password");
    $customer->save();  
}
$addresses = Mage::getModel("customer/address");

    $addresses->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
        ->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
        ->setMiddleName($customer->getMiddlename())
        ->setLastname($customer->getLastname())
        ->setCountryId($country)
        ->setCity($city)
        ->setTelephone($phone)
        ->setStreet($address)
        ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
        ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

try{
    $addresses->save();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
}

// Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);

// Configure Notification
$quote->setSendConfirmation(1);

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    //print_r($product);
    if(isset($_POST['optionsss']))
    {
        $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => $quantity,'options'=>array($optionsss=>$color))));
    }
    else
    {
        $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => $quantity)));
    }



// Set Sales Order Billing Address
$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
    'customer_address_id' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'firstname' => $fname,
    'middlename' => '',
    'lastname' => $lname,
    'suffix' => '',
    'company' => '',
    'street' => array(
        '0' => $address,
        '1' => ''
    ),
    'city' => $city,
    'country_id' => $country,
    'region' => '',
    'postcode' => '111',
    'telephone' => $phone,
    'fax' => '',
    'vat_id' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
        ));

// Set Sales Order Shipping Address
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
    'customer_address_id' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'firstname' => $fname,
    'middlename' => '',
    'lastname' => $lname,
    'suffix' => '',
    'company' => '',
    'street' => array(
        '0' => $address,
        '1' => ''
    ),
    'city' => $city,
    'country_id' => $country,
    'region' => '',
    'postcode' => '111',
    'telephone' => $phone,
    'fax' => '',
    'vat_id' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
        ));
if ($shipprice == 0) {
    $shipmethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
}

// Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
        ->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');

// Set Sales Order Payment
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'cashondelivery'));
Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::XML_PATH_EMAIL_ENABLED, "1");
// Collect Totals & Save Quote
$quote->collectTotals()->save();

try {
    // Create Order From Quote
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
    $service->submitAll();
    $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);

    try {
        //print_r($order);
                $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comments);
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n");
    $order->save();
                Mage::log('email sent');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}



// Resource Clean-Up
$quote = $customer = $service = null;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    header('Location: ../');
}
```

i do some changes but just symbol changed pkr to aed not price effected from 28 to 1 in backend.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7981/magento-set-currency-when-creating-order-programmatically

Comment: i already tried this but just change symbol not convert currency.

Comment: you have to set currency rate in magento backend.

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/currency-rates-update.html

Comment: currency rate already set.